# Trying to unravel a recursive Python program

Tags: python, recursion, loops

I am writing a simple cryptogram solver and am having trouble 'unrolling' a recursive function. I must unroll it for other reasons, otherwise I would leave it recursive.

Here's the idea: I have a variable number of lists, each with words in them. The function's job is to go through each list and, after checking that the word fits in the current alphabet setup, find it's score. So if you have the following lists:

```
LIST1: [the, and, can,...]
LIST2: [kids, cars, knee,...]
LIST3: [talks, walks, music,...]
...
```

and the function needs to go through each list (in order) and try to find the best sentence. (I have a scoring algorithm that it calls to compare.) It starts with the first word in the first list, then iterates the second list until it finds a word that works, then starts iterating the third list until it finds a word in that list that works, etc. Once it exhausts the words in the 3rd list, it should then go back to the second and find the next word that works, continuing the process until it's done.

I tried using the Product function, but that doesn't work the right way...that just gives me all possible combinations, and technically works, but is not very efficient.

```
def find_sentence():
cycle through first list:
cycle through second list:
if word works:
start cycling through third word list.
else: 
keep cycling through 2nd word list.
...
```

Keep going until we have gone through all word lists, finding a score that is above a threshold..

Any help?

From Bakuriu's response:
Thanks for your fast reply! I'm not that great at Python, but I don't think this is working the way I need it to. Your solution is similar to the Product method in that it's goal is to find all words that will work (or fit a score.) The method I need to use is : 1. Start with the 1st word in the 1st list. 2. Start iterating the next list of words. 3. As soon as one of those words works, start going through the 3rd list, etc. 4. When you've reached the end (to the last list of words) and find a candidate, you now have a solution, as you have one word in each list that works. 5. If, say, a word in list 3 does not fit, you must go back to list 2 and CONTINUE searching through that list, finding the next word that works, moving on to start list 3 OVER AGAIN, and continuing until nothing works or you've reached the end. I hope this is clear. Please let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: That was my response, not Bakuriu´s, he just edited.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need recursion here at all, actually.

```py
def find_sentence(*variable_number_of_lists):
    out = []
    for eachlist in variable_number_of_lists:
        for word in eachlist:
           if scoreword(out, word) > threshhold:
               # presumably, your 'scoreword' function would take in the current
               # list of okayed words in order to find the most recent one for use
               # in your scoring, if I've understood the problem correctly
               out.append(word)
               break

    return out
```

Comment: Your edit is exactly what this does.  Note the `break` statement.